# git cannot apply binary patch *** without full index line

Tags: git

When I try to apply a patch from a file, I see

```
error: cannot apply binary patch to 'my/resource.png' without full index line
error: my/resource.png: patch does not apply
```

I added `my/resource.png` in the commit from which I made the patch. How can I enabled full-index support?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Checkout the branch from which you want to create the patch. Run this command:

```
git diff-index 79fd4d7 --binary > ~/Desktop/my-patch
```

Where `79fd4d7` is a placeholder for the commit that came right before the range of commits you want to diff. (e.g. I want a patch that contains the first three commits below:

```
aaa02b0 third commit mine
aabbbcc second commit mine
bb82aed first commit mine
79fd4d7 old commit
```

Then checkout your new branch and run `git apply ~/Desktop/my-patch`

Comment: Note that the important thing here is the `--binary` command line option which is supported by both  `diff` and `diff-index`.

Comment: @kangear just worked it out, add `--reject`, so `git apply --reject filename.diff` will apply what it can and reject the rest

Comment: Why does this work when an ordinary git apply doesn't?

Comment: What is placeholder here? Is it commit number?

Comment: Tola Odejayi, `git apply` is not the problem. `git diff` is.

Comment: @ViruMax Yes, it's the commit number, which you can find with `git log`. It might be a much longer number than the numbers shown in this example.

Answer (score 7):

I want to post another way if you have **only deleted some files** and get the same message. Because I didn't had access to the source code anymore (through reset to another commit), I needed another solution (instead of creating a new patch file).

Therefore I deleted the following parts from my patch file:

```
diff --git a/MyProject/Libraries/some.dll b/MyProject/Libraries/some.dll
deleted file mode 100644
index a0908d7..0000000
Binary files a/MyProject/Libraries/some.dll and /dev/null differ
diff --git a/MyProject/Libraries/some.dll.mdb b/MyProject/Libraries/some.dll.mdb
deleted file mode 100644
index d3c3912..0000000
Binary files a/MyProject/Libraries/some.dll.mdb and /dev/null differ
```

Afterwards I could apply my patch file with success! Don't know why he wants to make a binary compare on a deleted file ...

Comment: NB even if you have reset your repo you still can reach reset commits via git reflog.