# git p4 submit failing when submitting image files

Tags: git-p4

I'm trying to submit some image files to `perforce` through `git-p4`. I'm getting the error below when I run `git p4 submit`. Can any one check this?

```
error: cannot apply binary patch to 'common/test image/ui-bg_glass.png' without full index line
error: common/test image/ui-bg_glass.png: patch does not apply
Unfortunately applying the change failed!
No commits applied.
```

Comment: hope help [git-cannot-apply-binary-patch-without-full-index-line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152171/git-cannot-apply-binary-patch-without-full-index-line)